# UIPrintInteractionController presentAnimated - slow and hangs the device?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am using `UIPrintInteractionController presentAnimated` to present a print dialog from a button in a `UIActionSheet`.

As soon as I touch the button, there are ~10 seconds in which the device does nothing visible and the action sheet remains on the screen. Then the action sheet is removed and the print dialog is displayed.

If I try to show an activity indicator BEFORE I call `presentAnimated`, it doesn't show until these ~10 seconds are over, and then it starts showing briefly until the print dialog covers it.

Is there anything that I can do to tell the user that something is going on and the device did not hang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still don't know what's causing this, but there's an obvious workaround which I somehow missed... call `presentAnimated` after a short delay to allow the action sheet to be dismissed and the activity indicator to start rolling.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but might help someone: Besides informing the user that it takes long, you can also speedup the process by setting the property `showsPageRange` of the `UIPrintInteractionController` instance to NO. In my case this reduced the time to popup the print dialog from 8 seconds to 0.7 seconds.

Comment: Definitely helped! There was a giant lag even in the Simulator and setting showsPageRange to NO makes it instant. Looks like that option is going into Settings now.

Answer (score 1):

//dataWithContentsOfURL is blocking call, it should be called like: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{ pc.printingItem = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"urlString"]]; 
});`

It will present the UIPrintInteractionController immediately.